# Try and Except not printing line under it python

Tags: python, try-except

I am making a very basic calculator and I am currently struggling with having my Error Exception print the line under it in python.

My code includes:

```py
loops = int(input("How many math problems do you need: "))

for i in range(loops):
    while True:
        method = input("What math method would you like to use. m = multiplication, d = division, a = addition, s = subtraction:, ex = exponent: ")  
        try: 
            if method in ['m','M','d','D','a','A','s','S','Ex','ex','EX','eX']:
                break
        except:
            print("Error your method is not viable")
    
    while True:
        num1 = input("What is the first number you want to input into your method: ")
        try: 
            num1 = float(num1)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Error your first number needs to be a number")

    while True:
        num2 = input("What is the second number you want to input into your method: ")
        try: 
            num2 = float(num2)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Error your second number needs to be a number")

    if method in ['m', 'M']:
        finalans = num1 * num2
        print("Your answer is",finalans)
    if method in ['d', 'D']:
        finalans = num1 / num2
        print("Your answer is",finalans)
    if method in ['a', 'A']:
        finalans = num1 + num2
        print("Your answer is",finalans)
    if method in ['s', 'S']:
        finalans = num1 - num2
        print("Your answer is",finalans)
    if method in ['Ex', 'ex', 'EX', 'eX']:
        finalans = num1 ** num2
        print("Your answer is",finalans)
    exit()
```

On line 10 I am having trouble making the except print out the line under it does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When I run this program the first Try-Except does not print the line under it and instead returns and reruns.

Comment: What input are you providing that causes this behavior?

Comment: I think I understand. `if method in ['m','M','d','D','a','A','s','S','Ex','ex','EX','eX']` will not raise any Exceptions. Even if `method` is not in the list, you will not raise an exception. Hence, never entering the `except` block. This condition will only produce `True` or `False`. If `True` we break, if `False` we continue on with the loop.

Comment: No exception will be thrown if the input method is not in that list, so it won't hit the exception handler. You can add `else:` and then print the message.

Comment: You should just put the `print()` in the `if` block. There's no exception.

Comment: You don't even need an `else`. The loop only continues if you don't break.

Answer (score 1):

There are tho mistakes I can see the first is that you forgot to indent everything under line 3 `for i in range(loops):` and to `exit()`. the second is that `if method in [...]` dose not throw any errors. So you ether have to replace it with `[...].index(method)` or replace

```
try: 
    if method in [...]:
        break
except:
    print("<error message>")
```

with

```
if method in [...]:
    break
else:
    print("<error message>")
```

where `[...]` is your list of all possible operations

Answer (score 0):

I you want to use exceptions to handle invalid methods you can use it like this:

```
loops = int(input("How many math problems do you need: "))

for i in range(loops):
    while True:
        method = input("What math method would you like to use. m = multiplication, d = division, a = addition, s = subtraction:, ex = exponent: ")  
        try: 
            if method not in ['m','M','d','D','a','A','s','S','Ex','ex','EX','eX']:
                raise Exception()
            break
        except:
            print("Error your method is not viable")
```

However is much better to handle it with a simple `if-else` directive:

```
loops = int(input("How many math problems do you need: "))

for i in range(loops):
    while True:
        method = input("What math method would you like to use. m = multiplication, d = division, a = addition, s = subtraction:, ex = exponent: ")   
        if method in ['m','M','d','D','a','A','s','S','Ex','ex','EX','eX']:
            break
        else:
            print("Error your method is not viable")
```

Comment: Ahhh I see thank you very much kind sir also my bad on indenting the exit()